# Find all the child test suites in TFS using C#

Tags: c#, tfs

I would like get all the child test suites under a parent test suite in TFS using C# code. Let me know if anyone has done this.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Shamrai's answer below? any update?

Answer (score 0):

I have create the simple app based on [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string teamProjectName = "TFSCMMI";
            int parentTestSuiteId = 819; // or test plan id

            var TFSCurrentProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs-srv:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"));
            var testStore = TFSCurrentProjectCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();

            var teamProject = testStore.GetTeamProject(teamProjectName);

            var testSuite = teamProject.TestSuites.Find(parentTestSuiteId);
            if (testSuite.TestSuiteType == TestSuiteType.StaticTestSuite)
            {
                var staticSuite = testSuite as IStaticTestSuite;
                foreach (var childSuite in staticSuite.Entries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Test suite id " + childSuite.Id + " name '" + childSuite.Title + "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```